# How do I add a custom delimiter to this context menu search?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the extension "Custom right-click menu" to add a custom site search. When I use the context menu, it adds spaces to the search term. I need it to have a +.

```
var search = crmAPI.getSelection() || prompt('Please enter a search query');
var url    = 'https://www.subetalodge.us/list_all/search/%s/mode/name';
var toOpen = url.replace(/%s/g,search);
window.open(toOpen, '_blank');
```

Comment: What have you tried? There's no attempt here to use plus signs. Seems like you'd need to do another `replace()`, right?

Answer (score 0):

This correction should work:

```
var toOpen = url.replace(/%s/g,search.replaceAll(' ', '+'))
```

Whole code:

```
var search = crmAPI.getSelection() || prompt('Please enter a search query'); var url = 'https://www.subetalodge.us/list_all/search/%s/mode/name'; var toOpen = url.replace(/%s/g,search.replaceAll(' ', '+')); window.open(toOpen, '_blank');
```